# Access to class variable

Tags: c++, polymorphism, getter

I've got a problem with access to an object, which is a variable of a class. The inheritance and relationship looks as follows:

```
#include "X.h"

class Y
{   
    X object; 

public:
    X & getObject();
};
```

Then another file/class:

```
#include "Y.h"

class Z : public Y
{
    X object2;
public:
    X & getObject2();
};
```

And finally a class which got a vector of pointers to objects.

```
 #include "Z.h"

 class XYZ
 {
    vector<Y*> cont;  //contains objects of class type Z and Y
 };
```

If I want to get access to `object` variable, I simply write

```
cont[index]->getObject();
```

But there is no way to get access to the `object2`, the compiler does not even see such a method as `getObject2()`. I presume that my description isn't clear, but anyway I hope you will help me.

Comment: All other things aside, passing out non-const references to member variables is a bad idea, because your class just lost control over its internal state -- *having* that control is the whole idea of writing object-oriented software in the first place.

Comment: getObject2 is a function of the derived class and you store pointers to the parent class. See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/121-pointers-and-references-to-the-base-class-of-derived-objects/ for solutions.

Comment: @Chiel the comment in the code clearly states that the vector holds objects of *both* types.

Comment: @davmac I know, but the container type of a pointer to the base class, which means that dereferencing gives you only access to the base functionality.

Comment: @davmac The only objects the vector contains are pointers to `Y`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you could call that function if the object is not a `Z`?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, and that's exactly why this question was posed. In other words, how can I call a derived class' method from a base class pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is determining whether you *can* call the `getObject2` method. The comment in your code says that the vector holds both types of object, so how can you be sure that any one particular object is a `Z` and not just a `Y`? If it is a `Y`, the `getObject2` method isn't available and you must not try to call it.

You have several options. Here are some of them:

- One solution is to use two separate vectors for the two distinct types:

  ```
  vector<Y*> conty;
  vector<Z*> contz;
  ```

  However, this won't maintain the ordering between different object types. Whether this is a problem or not depends on your purpose.
- Another solution is to cast the pointer to the desired type -

  ```
  (Z *)(cont[index])->getObject2();
  ```

  ... but you can only do this if you know the actual type of the pointed-to object. You could use `dynamic_cast` if you are unsure:

  ```
  Z *z = dynamic_cast<Z *>(cont[index]);
  if (z != nullptr) {
      z.getObject2();
  }
  ```
- Yet another solution is to add `getObject2` into the base class, `Y`, and make it virtual so that it can be overridden in `Z`. You can have the implementation in `Y` just return `nullptr`. You would need to change the return type of `getObject2`, so that it returns a pointer rather than a reference.

  ```
  class Y
  {   
      X object; 

  public:
      X & getObject();
      virtual X * getObject2();
  };
  ```

Which option is best depends on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need virtual functions. Your code may be changed in such a way:

```
#include "X.h"

class Y
{   
    X object; 

public:
    virtual X & getObject()
    {
        return object;
    }

};
```

and:

```
#include "Y.h"

    class Z : public Y
    {
        X object2;
    public:
        virtual X & getObject()
        {
            return object2;
        }
    };
```

So at any call of

```
cont[index]->getObject();
```

at runtime there is look in virtual table of some entity, pointer to which is in cont[index]. If it is pointer to Y object, getObject() of Y class is called and if it is pointer to Z object, getObject() of Z class is called.

Comment: I believe that this does not address the question. The OP wants to be able to access both the first and second object in the case that they have a `Z` object (this is not explicit, but it is implied).

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to try is *really* to call `object2()`, you could try with a `dynamic_cast` to type `Z*`. In the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) you have a full explanation on how to use it (e.g.: it will fail returning a NULL pointer if you are passing a pointer to an object of type Y)

```
Z* p_z = dinamic_cast<Z*> (cont[index])
if (p_z)
   std::cout << p_z->getObject2();
```

Answer (score 0):

`cont` is a vector of `Y*`. This means its members expose only the API defined on the `Y` class. `getObject2()` is defined on its descendant only. Even if the members in the vector are in fact instances of `Z`, as long as they are accessed as instances of type Y, then only `Y`'s interface is available.

If you want `getObject2()` to be available you need to do one of three things:
1. Add a virtual `getObject2()` method to `Y`
2. Move `getObject2()` function completely to `Y`
3. Make `cont` a `vector<Z*>`